# How to change the primary color in ng-bootstrab

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am testing the `Bootstrab-4` components for my `Angular` app.

How do I change the `primary` color of of `bootstrab`? Is there a sass version I have to import to overwrite the variables in ng-bootstrab?

Comment: check out [this link](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#global-changes) for more details, how to change saas variables

Comment: Can you tell where I can see something about the variables? I only see what bootstrab is going to change in version 4.
I know how I change variables in bootstrab stand alone, but how can I change the theme in ng-bootstrab?

Comment: take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21078) & [this link](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/)